# Characterization of ellipticity for linear differential operators

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-operators

Let $P(D)$ be a differential operator of order $m$. I would like to show that $P(D)$ is elliptic *if* for some open and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and for some real $s$ and $c>0$
and all $\varphi\in \mathscr{D}(\Omega)$:
$$\|\varphi\|_{s+m}\leq c\|P(D)\varphi\|_s.$$

Many thanks in advance for your help.